# Set Transient in wordpress to get tweets

Tags: twitter, wordpress

I am following a tutorial to get embed tweets  [here](http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/how-to-use-the-twitter-api-in-wordpress/)

but no luck, result `No tweets found.`

i just changed the username to my, what i doing wrong?

need to configure something in functions.php or in database??

or setting `set_transient();` ?

(i put the code in footer)

please help

Comment: The code looks good, to see immediate results, why don't you try to reduce the $cacheTime to 0 while you test?